# Pass a c# object of type HashTable as argument

Tags: c#, arguments, hashtable

Is it possible (in C#) to pass an object of type HashTable as a parameter to a method?

I'm trying to, but it seems (at debug-time) impossible to reference the object (i'm getting a null reference object).

Comment: Show us how you are passing the HashTable object - it will help us help you.

Comment: As an aside, if you have a choice, use a generic Dictionary rather than a non-type-safe `HashTable`.  You'll avoid certain classes of runtime bugs, and your code will be faster due to having to do less casting.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible (in C#) to pass an object of type HashTable as a parameter to a method?

It is possible.

```
public void MyMethod(HashTable ht) {
```

> (i'm getting a null reference object).

This is probably because you're passing `null`.